# Unanswered questions in my favorite tags

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions, tag-watching

How can I see unanswered questions in my favorite tags in Stack Overflow. I tried first click on main `Unanswered` button and  then choosing `my tags` tab but as you can see in the picture below these filtered questions all have accepted answer

[image]

Could any one please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When they have an *accepted* answer the `2` resp `3` will be yellow. [Those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330988/remoteplaybackclient-stop-not-getting-callback) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343707/cordovaresourceapi-import-unresolved-phonegap) don't have an accepted answer.

If you want *unanswered* questions, check out the fourth tab labeled "no answers".

When you're looking for unanswered questions in specific tags, unfortunately you'll have to [do that manually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18545/view-or-search-for-unanswered-questions-with-a-certain-tag):

> https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/$yourTag